# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<character> has no method 'Logic'

Tags: javascript

```
var Player1 = new character;
```

When I attempt to call the function with `Player1.Logic();` or `Logic();` I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<character> has no method 'Logic'
```

Here is my character.js class file:

```
(function(window){

function character(){
}

function Logic(){
    console.log("new character loaded!");
}

window.character = character;
}(window));
```

Should I be declaring the function differently or calling it differently?
Everything else seems to work fine except for this.  The only luck that I've had so far is with declaring functions with event handlers.

Comment: Where is the HTML5? I see JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello right there **in the tag** don't you see it? :-P

Comment: Missing some `Logic.prototype.character` stuff.

Comment: @Mindbreaker other way around.

Comment: Oh sorry: `character.prototype.Logic`

Comment: @JakeMesser remember to check off the answer that helped you, so if people in the future have the same issue, they know where to start :-D

Comment: @JakeMesser please do not add "[SOLVED]" to your question. We all see it is "solved" with the green check next to your accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that is because the `Logic` function has **nothing** to do with the `character` function.

And the `Logic` function is inside the local scope of that IIFE.

---

Here is something you *could* do:

```
var Character = (function(){

    function Character (){}

    Character.prototype.logic = function(){
        console.log("new character loaded!");
    }

    return Character

})();
```

And you can use it like so:

```
var myCharacter = new Character();
myCharacter.logic();
```

<sub>Side node: Capitalized methods are usually used for classes and lowercase methods are usually used for regular functions and class methods.</sub>

Comment: *IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Comment: No disrespect intended, just clarifying for any potentially stumped readers. Honestly, this is the first time I've come across anything related to a wiki on SO—I'm a bit lost there.

Comment: @AndréDion **ANY** answer you can edit... that is how the Stack Exchange works :-)

Comment: Updated @WesleyMurch :-D

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your Logic() function outside of your character() function...

Try this:

```
(function (window) {

    function character() {
        this.Logic=function() {
            console.log("new character loaded!");
        }
    }

    window.character = character;
}(window));
var Player = new character();
character.Logic();
```